# Python dictionary: number of keys with specific number of values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a huge dictionary that looks like this:

```
data = {'this': [{'DT': 100}], 'run': [{'NN': 215}, {'VB': 2}], 'the': [{'NNP': 6}, {'JJ': 7}, {'DT': 39517}]}
```

What I would like to to do is to run enquires that would return ,for example, the number of keys with exactly two values, in which case the answer is one because `'run'` is the only one with exactly two values `{'NN': 215}` & `{'VB': 2}`

I think this could be done with regular expression but could not find out how.

Comment: RegEx is used to parse strings, not any other data type.

Comment: You're dict is malformed also please pretty print to help us out.

Comment: you have duplicated key 'run', and try to use filter, like filter(lambda s: len(data[s])==2, data) to filter the dictionary

Comment: Fixed the duplicate key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
print len( filter( lambda x: len( x ) == 2, data.values() ) )
```

The lambda returns true when the length of an item is 2. `filter()` selects only those items where the lambda returns true, and then we count the length of the sequence returned by `filter()`. `data.values()` allows us to filter on the values from the dict rather than the keys (which is what plain `data` would've given us). Since you only wanted the count, the values are all that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `regex` to achieve this. Regex are for parsing the strings. Better way is to create a new list to store the `key` with value as list of `len() == 2`:

```
data = {'this': [{'DT': 100}], 'run': [{'NN': 215}, {'VB': 2}], 'the': [{'NNP': 6}, {'JJ': 7}, {'DT': 39517}]}
key_list = [k for k, v in data.items() if len(v) == 2]
# key_list => ['run']
```

To get the list of such values, call `len` as:

```
>>> len(key_list)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the lengths and count the desired length.

```
>>> map(len, data.values()).count(2)
1
```